# Kerberos - KDC and IIS on same machine

Tags: active-directory, iis-7.5, kerberos

I have one domain controller which must act as Kerberos KDC and a IIS server running on that same domain controller. I need to set up an Integrated Windows Authentication where a domain user can browse the IIS server authenticating with Kerberos. My question is: do I still have to create a keytab file for the IIS even though IIS is on the KDC itself?